# Remove bootstrap nav-link hover background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to remove the background color of nav-link hover by setting it to transparent but they still show a background when being hovered. I would like to change the hover color for the text only like the nav-brand but cannot figure how. Could someone help me with this please? I really appreciate it.
Here is my HTML (ejs):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Ben Nguyen's Website</title>
      
      <!-- Bootstrap 5.2.0 -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.3.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f71ab2a16d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,200&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
      <!-- CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark>
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ben's</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Projects</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <!-- Carousel Section -->
        
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
              aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
              aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
              aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/76.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.496);">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                  <div class="text-white text-center">
                    <h1 class="mb-3">Hello, World!!!</h1>
                    <h5 class="mb-4">A Person</h5>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg m-2 button-contactMe" href="/" target="_blank" role="button">More About
                      Me!!!</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/77.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="mask" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                  <div class="text-white text-center">
                    <h2>Hello Again</h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg m-2"
                      href="/" target="_blank" role="button">A Button</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/78.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                  <div class="text-white text-center">
                    <h2>Hello Again Again</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel Section -->
    
    
    <!-- MDB -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.3.0/mdb.min.js"
></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p>2022</p>
  </div>
</footer>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navbar Section */

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 15px;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-icons {
    margin-left: 1000px;
}

.nav-link {
    color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #e35454d7;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #30264fd7;
}

.navbar-brand {
    color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #e35454d7;
}

.button-contactMe:hover {
    background-color: #100f1fcb;
}


/* Carousel Section */


.carousel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

/* Footer Section */

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

I use express to render ejs files:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("list");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started successfully");
});
```

[Expected result (Nav-brand hover)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oScrJ.png)

[Current problem (Nav-link hover)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTFM3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target you need to address to make a transparent background is **.navbar ul li:hover** and not the anchor.

See the working example below.

```css
/* Navbar Section */

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-icons {
  margin-left: 1000px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
}

.navbar ul li:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #e35454d7;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #30264fd7;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #e35454d7;
}

.button-contactMe:hover {
  background-color: #100f1fcb;
}


/* Carousel Section */

.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}


/* Footer Section */

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ben Nguyen's Website</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap 5.2.0 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.3.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f71ab2a16d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,200&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark>
          <div class=" container-fluid ">
              <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">Ben's</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button " data-bs-toggle="collapse " data-bs-target="#navbarNav " aria-controls="navbarNav " aria-expanded="false " aria-label="Toggle navigation ">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav ">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                  <li class="nav-item active ">
                      <a class="nav-link " href="/ ">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                      <a class="nav-link " href="/ ">Projects</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                      <a class="nav-link " href="/ ">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <!-- Carousel Section -->
        
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators " class="carousel slide " data-bs-ride="true ">
          <div class="carousel-indicators ">
            <button type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide-to="0 " class="active "
              aria-current="true " aria-label="Slide 1 "></button>
            <button type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide-to="1 "
              aria-label="Slide 2 "></button>
            <button type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide-to="2 "
              aria-label="Slide 3 "></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner ">
            <div class="carousel-item active ">
              <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/76.jpg " class="d-block w-100 " alt="... ">
              <div class="mask " style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.496); ">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100 ">
                  <div class="text-white text-center ">
                    <h1 class="mb-3 ">Hello, World!!!</h1>
                    <h5 class="mb-4 ">A Person</h5>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg m-2 button-contactMe " href="/ " target="_blank " role="button ">More About
                      Me!!!</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/77.jpg " class="d-block w-100 " alt="... ">
              <div class="mask " style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); ">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100 ">
                  <div class="text-white text-center ">
                    <h2>Hello Again</h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg m-2 "
                      href="/ " target="_blank " role="button ">A Button</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/78.jpg " class="d-block w-100 " alt="... ">
              <div class="mask " style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); ">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100 ">
                  <div class="text-white text-center ">
                    <h2>Hello Again Again</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev " type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide="prev ">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon " aria-hidden="true "></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden ">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next " type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide="next ">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon " aria-hidden="true "></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden ">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel Section -->
    
    
    <!-- MDB -->
<script
  type="text/javascript "
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.3.0/mdb.min.js "
></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
</body>

<footer id="footer ">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <p>2022</p>
  </div>
</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try display: block; and then give that bg color or whatever you intend to do... or you should inspect element on the browser and can try styling there... hope it helps